# Calculate new subscription cost on upgrade / downgrade

Tags: php, subscription

I am currently developing a subscription system for a web application.
I need help regarding the approach for new subscription costs when a user decides to downgrade or upgrade their account.

I created a image to make an example of a user that keeps changing levels.

[image]

A user can choose to pay each month, quarter or year.

I want to add a discount when the user decides to downgrade. The discount is currently factored into the new cost using this formula:

[final plan cost] = [new plan cost] * 12 - [discount] / [12 - month / 3 - quarter / 1 - year]

If we have a user that keeps changing plans like this, how can I calculate the discount dynamically? It's easy for one change - I can take the difference between the two plans and multiply it for each payment that was made before. But I need some help regarding the approach for several changes, and how I can keep track of the discount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put all that information in a database table and just call the cells. If the user it at the plan where they are getting the discount based on the sub; then
eg 
if(price is this)
 discount is {discount value from the database} x price of subscription..
You will not have to worry if someone changes their subscription in the middle of the month, all you have to do is put that information in a different table and at the end of the month all the application would do is apply the new subscription and do the calculations. It is not hard just the approach..

Comment: Yes i currently got all this data stored in a database, and i think i just came up with a way calculating this taking data from the db after reading this. Thanks :-)